# Fluid object, array shows only number of entrys

Tags: typo3, mask, fluid

I have a Typo Server with fluid and the Mask extension.
One of my mask elements has a content element so I can render in some other content stuff. 
I can do this with:

```
<f:if condition="{data.tx_mask_grid_items_item}">
    <f:for each="{data.tx_mask_grid_items_item}" as="data_item">    
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_mask.content">{data_item.uid}</f:cObject>   
    </f:for>
</f:if>
```

A little bit later I need some information from that content element. No problem, all datas are stored in the data object, except arrays. They are in the data object, but they only show the entrys of the arrays. Like:

```
 tx_mask_grid_modal_texte => '2' (1 chars)
```

But I need the values of that array. Anyone know how I can access that array?

Answer (score 0):

You have relations (IRRE) where only the number of relations are stored in the field of the record. the relations are stored in mm-records.

You can access the related records with a [dataprocessor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html?highlight=dataprocessor), especially a [`DatabaseQueryProcessor`](https://typo3worx.eu/2018/05/dataprocessing-fluid-templates/#toc_7).

Comment: Thats a typo Script. But I need the data in my Fluid template. How can I access them there?

Comment: there is some typoscript where you can define data for your CEs. AFAIR it was `mask.tt_content.my_own_ce.settings.my_variable`